# Items in background get focus after something in foreground is clicked

Tags: android, background, focus, sencha-touch-2, cordova-2.0.0

Using Sencha Touch 2.0.1.1 and Cordova 2.0.0, I'm having trouble with the focus of elements.

In multiple situations, elements in the background gain focus after an element in the foreground disappears by a tap.

- After an Ext.Msg.alert()'s OK button is clicked, the focus immediatly shifts to an underlying textfield behind the mask in the background
- When clicking the slideButton on WNielson's facebook menu, the focus immediatly shifts to the searchfield that's 'below' the slideButton (https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation)
- When clicking a list item on WNielson's facebook menu, I get instantly get redirected to a link that's 'below' the menu.

This occurs on Android <strike>and iOS</strike> **only**, but not in Chrome on pc or iOS. I've tried disabling the background element/view until the foreground element is gone, but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Is this a bug in sencha touch?

Edit: I've uploaded an example on http://www.senchafiddle.com/full/!NxY8s/, view it with an android device, and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior once, the problem was there were elements that were listening to click events instead of just tap events as generated by sencha.